# How to mosaic/align multispectral georeferenced images into one merged file with GDAL

Tags: gdal, mosaic, multi-band

I am trying to work my head around how to make mosaic from georeferenced multispectral images. Header of those images already contains information about GPS location.
Separate image is saved as *.tif file and consist of 5 separate bands. Ultimately I would like to make one big TIFF file which would include all multispectral images merged into one. Also I would like to execute merging algorithmically with the use of Python.
For purpose of testing I am just trying to align two of those multispectral images (pic1.tif and pic2.tif) into one. See a screenshot of pics: [pics](https://prnt.sc/v72i2i).

[image]

With some googling I found out that this can be done with the use of GDAL. Since my images already include information about location I just excecuted

```
command = gdal_merge.py -o mosaic.tif -of gtiff pic1.tif pic2.tif 
output = subprocess.check_output(command)
```

The command executed succesfully, but the output image (mosaic.tif) sems to be equal to pic2.tif.

After that I also tried to manualy insert GCP points with:

```
gdal_translate -gcp 620.5 456.0 33.98 44.839 -of GTiff pic1.tif newpic1.tif
gdal_translate -gcp  620.5 456.0 34 44.63 -of GTiff pic2.tif newpic2.tif
```

where the numbers: 620.5 - 456.0 - x - x represents respectively: image_center_x - image_center_y - longitude - latitude

After execution of:

```
python C:/pathtofile/gdal_merge.py -of GTiff -o mosaic.tif newpic1.tif newpic2.tif
```

also no luck.

Can tell me what I am doing wrong and what should I change/do, to make mosaic?

I am open to another solution if GDAL is not appropriate for this task.

Comment: Can you try adding the `-separate` argument to your command? For example: `command = gdal_merge.py -o mosaic.tif -of gtiff -separate pic1.tif pic2.tif ` Adding this argument will tell GDAL you want the input rasters stored as separate bands in the merged output.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried what you said and it seems that gdal merges the two pictures, because now the file is twice as large. But, now the photo viewer says that it cannot open it? Do you think I need to use Geotransform() function, because right now the GPS data in pic1.tif and pic2.tif is inserted with exiftool? In other words  GPS data can be found for each picture in properties under longitude and latitude. I dont know if gdal looks for this data in tiff header.

Comment: run `gdalinfo pic1.tif` and read the output. do this for your input images (and the output image) and you will see what spatial information is included in the file.

Comment: Here you can see the [output](https://prnt.sc/v86uv3). I only added one gcp point in the middle of an image, because I only have this data (GPS coordinates where the image was taken). As you can see the image contains 5 bands. Is it even posible to use gdal for mosaicing, if you have only one gcp point for each image? Is there another aproach I can take to do this taks?

Comment: Does each input file have one band of the same spectrum and you want a spatially-larger (with the overlaps knitted together) file with one band of imagery? // I think you need more GCPs per image to get scale and orientation for each input image.

Comment: Hello, yes - separate till image fille have one band of the same spectrum and yes - I am looking for option to make spatially-larger file with one band. Whit further research I found out that using GDAL wont help me, because as you said I would need more GCPs. But I am sure that there is a possibilty to align images in that way, beacuse you can do the same thing with pix3d software.